# Public IP Shows Up In Search Results Instead of Domain

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, website, iis-8.5, joomla

I have set up a website on my Proliant rack server (Running windows server 2012 R2) using IIS and Joomla as a CMS.

Everything works perfectly, except for one thing. Whenever I search up my website on Google, it shows my public IP instead of the domain name. It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaN2c.png), but instead, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icyk8.png). How do I get my domain name to show up instead of the IP? I have configured the FQDN of my server to be example.com.
My DNS records are as follows:

```
A record: Host:example.com, Points to: [my public IP]
CNAME: Host:www.example.com, Points to: example.com
```

I have set the `live_site` option in the Joomla config to `https://example.com/`.
I have also claimed my domain on Google search console, if that is important.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then your server is replying with full content to the IP address instead of answering with a redirect to the domain name and then replying with full content.
I suggest you look into this: [IIS7.5 redirect IP to domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/286295/iis7-5-redirect-ip-to-domain)